# Displaying search results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been looking around for hours today on how to display this list of strings I've created to an action result called "results". I was wondering if anyone knew how to display it on the .aspx page?

```
public class Testimonials   
{
    public string AddTestimonials { get; set; }
    public string SearchTestimonials { get; set; }

    public List<string> results = new List<string>();

    public void getSearchResults(string keyword)
    {
        string query = "SELECT content from Testimonial where Content like '%@p1%';"; //insert statement
        SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(@"");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", keyword);      // seting @p1 to the content
        db.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable results = new DataTable();
        results.Load(reader); //Loads remaining surgeon credentials into a data table.
        foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
        {
            string cont = row["content"].ToString();
            this.results.Add(cont);
        }
        db.Close();
    }
}



    public ActionResult Testimonials()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Testimonials(Testimonials model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (model.AddTestimonials != null)
        {
            string query = "Insert Testimonial (content,date,surgeonID) VALUES (@p1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@p2);"; //insert statement
            SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(@"");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", model.AddTestimonials);      // seting @p1 to the content
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Convert.ToString(Session["surgeonID"]));
            db.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            db.Close();
            return RedirectToAction("Testimonials");
        }
        if (model.SearchTestimonials != null)
        {
            model.getSearchResults(model.SearchTestimonials);
            return RedirectToAction("Testimonials");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I've tried "for each var" in many different variations with no success. This is the aspx so far:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared    /Site.Master"Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TEAM3OIE2S.Models.Testimonials    >"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent"     runat="server">
    Testimonials
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"     runat="server">
   <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <h2>Testimonials</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddTestimonials)%>
   <input type="submit" value="Add" />
<% } %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
 <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchTestimonials)%>
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />


<% } %>

</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes in your code.

```
public List<string> getSearchResults(string keyword)
{
    public List<string> results = new List<string>();
    //....
    foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
    {
        string cont = row["content"].ToString();
        this.results.Add(cont);
    }
    db.Close();
    return results;
}
```

now inside the controller

```
var results = new Testimonials().getSearchResults("blah");
return View("Testimonials", results);
```

Now at View

```
@model List<string>
@foreach (var result in Model)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => result)</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net MVC you need to pass "model" to "view" so you can access information from the view. Usually it is done by one of [`Controller.View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.100).aspx) methods that have model parameter.

It is not exactly clear to me what you are actually trying to display, but following should get you started:

```
public ActionResult Testimonials()
{
    getSearchResults("test");
    return View(result);
}
```